# I can't install install firebase-admin

Tags: python, python-2.7, firebase, anaconda, firebase-admin

I've got an error following:

```
MacBook-Air:Firebase takeyuki$ python -m pip install --upgrade firebase-admin
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.

... some lines are omitted ...

Installing collected packages: futures, googleapis-common-protos, grpcio, google-api-core, uritemplate, httplib2, google-auth-httplib2, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-core, google-resumable-media, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore, msgpack, cachecontrol, firebase-admin
  Found existing installation: futures 3.0.3
Cannot uninstall 'futures'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

This message mentions **futures** module seems not to belong to pip, but

```
MacBook-Air:Firebase takeyuki$ python -m pip list | grep futures
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
futures                            3.0.3
```

So, how can I fix it? Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you try the following steps?

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip==20.0.0
pip install futures --disable-pip-version-check
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Another option is to work in a virtualenv:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv -p python venv
source venv/bin/activate
python pip install firebase-admin
```

Update: the option that did actually work:

```
pip install --ignore-installed futures
```

Comment: Hi Nebulastic, after pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip==20.0.0, pip   gets not worked as 
```bash:
  File "/Users/takeyuki/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.3.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/distributions/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pip._internal.distributions.source import SourceDistribution
ImportError: cannot import name SourceDistribution
```

Comment: Also, I've updated my pip to 20.0.2 and follow your steps, but still the error has remained:

```bash:
    Found existing installation: futures 3.0.3
ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'futures'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Comment: What happens when you use a virtualenv?

Comment: Also, not working well
```bash:
MacBook-Air:devtmp takeyuki$ virtualenv -p python venv
Already using interpreter /Users/takeyuki/.pyenv/versions/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/python
New python executable in /Volumes/devtmp/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...source venv/bin/activate
python pip install firebase-admin
done.
MacBook-Air:devtmp takeyuki$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv) MacBook-Air:devtmp takeyuki$ python pip install firebase-admin
python: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: No, result is ```ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'futures'.```

Comment: pip install --ignore-installed futures

Answer (score 0):

i ran into a similar problem. when i installed firebase_admin 5.4.0 on Thonny IDE, everything worked fine.
so to install it on your machine, just rollback to that version.
i used
**sudo pip3 install firbase_admin==5.4.0**